# Extracting data from JsonArray using JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, arrays

I have a JsonArray something like this.

```
var json_array = [{ "text": "id", "size": 4}, { "text": "manifesto", "size": 4}, { "text": "also", "size": 4}, { "text": "leasing", "size": 4}, { "text": "23", "size": 4}];
```

Is there anyway to get me all the "text" property of this json_array in another array using Javascript/jQuery?

like:

```
var t_array = ["id","manifesto","also"....]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [$.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) to project the relevant information from your existing array into a new one:

```
var t_array = $.map(json_array, function(item) {
    return item.text;
});
```

Comment: Just curious (I don't use jQuery) - is that $.map function asynchronous?

Comment: @JKing, nope, it isn't. It builds and returns the array synchronously. The function it takes as an argument is not a callback, it's used to project the items of the new array.

Comment: ah. I've been spending too much time in node.js... every anonymous function passed as an arg to another function makes me think "Weeee! Asynchronous event driven programming!" Thanks for _nothing_, jQuery!

Answer (score 2):

```
var t_array = [];

for (var i=0; i< json_array.length; i++)
    t_array.push(json_array[i].text);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to build `t_array` by looping through `json_array`

Answer (score 1):

something like:

```
var t_array = [];
$.each(json_array,function(i,o) {
  t_array.push(o.text);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bouillard/2c66t/